# Getting MIME-Type of file using FtpClient

Tags: java, ftp

I am working on a download manager, that will support http/https/ftp protocols. I am using  `FTPClient` from the `Apache commons library` to download files via FTP. I want to be able to determine the `MIME-Type` of the file that is about to be downloaded. Please note that I  know how to use  the `retrieveFile` method from `FTPClient`. I just want to get `MIME-Type` of file like `audio/wma`.

Could any one please guide me to get this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you won't be able to get the MIME type of a file using FTP commands as it's not supported, therefore `FTPClient` has no support to provide that information. However, *after* you've downloaded the file you can use `org.apache.sling.commons.mime` to get the MIME type.

Comment: It is done using `FileNameMap fileNameMap = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();` `String contentType = fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor("file-path");` Thanks about your suggestion :)

Comment: Great, so you found another module/component to get the mime type. Congrats!